# Two dimensional array Qt, initialization and usage

Tags: c++, arrays, qt

Maybe I'm just tired and I don't think clear enough or maybe I am such a noob in Qt programming but I got problem with initializing and usage of two dimensional array.

I created OutputData class which looks like this:

```
#ifndef OUTPUTDATA_H
#define OUTPUTDATA_H

#include <QObject>
#include "algorithms/data/tabledata.h"
#include <QVector>
#include <QDebug>
class OutputData : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_ENUMS(direction)
public:
    explicit OutputData(const int xSize, const int ySize, QObject *parent = 0);
    enum direction {left, front, right, back };
    double rightDistance;
    double leftDistance;
    double frontDistance;
    int xShift;
    int yShift;
    direction currentDir;
    int  turnCount;
    int  currentDirection;
    TableData** table;
    QString toString();
    void saveFieldInfo();
signals:

public slots:

private:

};

#endif // OUTPUTDATA_H
```

and of course cpp file:

```
#include "outputdata.h"

OutputData::OutputData(const int xSize,const  int ySize, QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    // Nie chce mi sie bawić z ujemnymi wartościami to zaczynam od 2996 skrętu w prawo.
    //Jak kiedyś robot skręci 2996 razy pod rząd w lewo to się będę tym przejmował
    currentDir=front;
    currentDirection = 2996;

    rightDistance =0;
    leftDistance = 0;
    frontDistance = 0;
    xShift =0;
    yShift =0;
    turnCount =0;

    //   vector = new QVector<QVector<TableData*> >(10, QVector<TableData*>(10));
    table =new TableData*[ySize];
    for(int i = 0; i < ySize; i++){
        table[i] = new TableData[xSize];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < ySize; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < xSize; j++){
            table[i][j] = TableData();
        }
    }
}




void OutputData::saveFieldInfo(){
    qDebug() << "save field info " << "rightDistance " << rightDistance <<  " leftDistance" << leftDistance << " frontDistance " << frontDistance
             << " currentDirection " << currentDirection;
    table[yShift][xShift].fillWithData(rightDistance,leftDistance,frontDistance,currentDirection);
}


QString OutputData::toString(){
    QString* string = new QString("{\"rightDistance\": \"\"");
    string ->append(",\"leftDistance\": \"\"");
    string->append(",\"frontDistance\": \"\"");
    string->append(",\"xShift\": \"\"");
    string->append(",\"yShift\": \"\"");
    string->append(",\"currentDir\": \"\"");
    string->append(",\"turnCount\": \"\"");
    string->append(",\"currentDirection\": \"\"}");
    return *string;
}
```

`TableData` class is simple holder for primitive values such as direction, distance etc. Nothing special.

Here's my problem: I want to have two dimensional array of `TableData` where I can keep data which can be provided in random order but always with proper coordinates. (hope that this is understandable)

When I try to compile this code I receive error that I don't understand.

> /home/adam/Qt/5.2.1/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:979: błąd:
>   'QObject& QObject::operator=(const QObject&)' is private
>        Class &operator=(const Class &) Q_DECL_EQ_DELETE;
>               ^

(this error points at line **class TableData : public QObject** in TableData file)

and second:

> /home/adam/Dropbox/workspace/git/qt/Raspberry/Raspberry/algorithms/data/tabledata.h:7:
>   błąd: within this context  class TableData : public QObject
>          ^

(this error points at 979 line of  qglobal.h)

So I think (better: I'm pretty sure) I did something wrong. But I really don't know what!

Is there a better way to work on two dimensional array? How to initialize and use it? I know there plenty of examples on the web but most of them use **double** or **int** and I want to use my class `TableData`. They also make this arrays in specific function and I want that this array was available in whole class.

======= EDIT
As suggested I decide to use QVector but when I try to initialize it I got this error:

> /home/adam/Dropbox/workspace2013.02/magisterka/git/qt/Raspberry/Raspberry/algorithms/data/outputdata.cpp:18:
>   błąd: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are
>   'QVector >' and 'QVector >*')
>        table = new QVector >(10, QVector(10));
>              ^

in outputdata.h

```
 QVector<QVector<TableData*> > table;
```

in outputdata.cpp

```
  table = new QVector<QVector<TableData*> >(10, QVector<TableData*>(10));
```

This line generates error. How to fix it?

Later if I want to use this table did field of this table will be initialized or not?

Is this legal:

```
table[x][y].method();
```

or should I do it like this:

```
if(table[x][y] ==NULL){
 table[x][y] = new TableData();
}
    table[x][y].method();
```

Sorry for java style:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `TableData` class is a subclass of `QObject` and so cannot be copied or copy assigned. That's why you are getting the compilation errors.

Your array should work with pointers to `TableData` instances i.e. create your `TableData` instances using `new`. Your `table` declaration should be

```
TableData*** table;
```

Rather than use a built-in array though you might be better off using containers. I notice that you have a line commented out that is using a QVector of QVectors of `TableData*` so I'm not sure whether you are trying to port the container approach to built-in arrays or not. Probably best to stick with the containers unless you have a good reason not to.

---

To answer your edit, I think you are getting confused between Java and C++. In C++ you only need `new` to do dynamic memory allocation. It returns a pointer. Your `table` variable is already declared as a `QVector` rather than a pointer to one so the storage for it will be set up when you instantiate the class. All you need to do is something like

```
OutputData::OutputData(const int xSize,const  int ySize, QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent),
    table(ySize) // resize to ySize (empty) rows
{
    for(int i = 0; i < ySize; i++){
        QVector<TableData*>& row = table[i];
        row.resize(xSize); // Each TableData pointer will be initialised to NULL
        for(int j = 0; j < xSize; j++){
            row[j] = new TableData();
        }
    }
    // ...
```

Only `TableData` itself needs to be allocated with `new`. Since the `TableData` elements are pointers you will need to access them like

```
table[x][y]->method();
```

Comment: Another option would be to not derive from `QObject` since there doesn't appear to be any reason for this class to do so.

Comment: Thank you for answer I decided to use QVector. But I got another strange problem. Please check edited question.

Answer (score 2):

```
  QVector<QStringList> matrix{{"foo", "bar", "baz"}, {"hello", "world", "!"}};
  qDebug() << "output: " << matrix[0];
```

Will output :

> output:  ("foo", "bar", "baz")